# NextJS getStaticProps / getStaticPaths typeError: response is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm struggling with an error showing up in my terminal when testing on localhost. I've been getting an inconsistent message reading:

> error - TypeError: response is not a function

I'm having trouble figuring out why it happens, because it only shows up on maybe 1 out of 10 refreshes of the page, and there are no useful messages in the browser console. I don't even know if the problem is triggered by `getStaticPaths` or `getStaticProps`, because I can't include one without the other.

Anyone see what I'm missing? I've simplified the code to this:

```
const Reviews = props => {
    console.log("Reviews rendering");
    return (
        <Fragment>word</Fragment>
    );
};
 export async function getStaticPaths() {
      let config = await import("../../config/config");
      let axResponse = await axios.get(`https://${config.default.domain}/api/get/ti.php`);
      return {
            paths: axResponse.data.items.map(item=>({ params: { code: item } })),
            fallback: true
      };
 };
 export async function getStaticProps(context) {
      let config = await import("../../config/config");
      let axResponse = await axios.get(`${config.default.apiEndpoint_static}&sft=reviews&code=${context.params.code}`);
      return {
            props: {
                 asdf: "zxcv"
            }
      };
 };
```

The import of `config` is just a local json file that has stuff like the api endpoint, domain name, etc. I have a feeling this might be what NextJS doesn't like, but I'm not sure. It does work though.

I've also verified that the responses from the api are valid json with the expected data. Basically, `getStaticPaths` is pulling a list of top items so that only those items will be pre-rendered on the server, and `getStaticProps` is pulling reviews for each item so that they can be displayed. I'm purposely not doing anything with the reviews in this simplified demo, I just wanted to leave the line there in case it's part of the problem.

And here's a longer snippet from the terminal. Every "Reviews rendering" line is me hitting refresh on the browser. Maybe the fact that it only seems to happen after I've changed the file is meaningful.. Further refreshes don't seem to trigger the message.

> event - compiled successfully in 973 ms (1974 modules)
> Reviews rendering
> error - TypeError: response is not a function
> wait  - compiling /_error...
> event - compiled successfully in 937 ms (1974 modules)
> Reviews rendering
> Reviews rendering
> Reviews rendering

Comment: Do you have a `response` variable anywhere in your code? It doesn't seem like the error comes from that file (if that's really all you have in it). Do you have an API routes by any chance?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? Getting something similar in my code

Comment: I don't think I did, sorry : ( I don't remember for sure, but looking at the code now, I completely removed the server-side rendering part of the component. The problem is gone so there must have been something `Next.js` didn't like, but I have no idea what it was..